# Validate table data with regex in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a MSSQL table with large number of alpha numeric codes. I have to verify these codes are within certain characters. How do I write a SQL in MSSQL? Any advice ?

Codes Table

```
JFBBB22 -> Valid

JBBYB33 

AXBBB22 ->Invalid

LBBBB33
```

Code I am using in c# to validate..

```
Regex.IsMatch(code, "^[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ123456789]*$").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE code NOT LIKE '%[^BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ123456789]%'`

Comment: Perfect..That's what I  wanted.. I was struggling with regex in select.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select dbo.RegexMatch( N'123-45-6789', N'^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$' )
```

For the full documentation check [The MSDN  site for the official page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)